# Using constraints to define height minus a constant with storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, autolayout

I'm using layout constraints to make my views display correctly, but I'm stuck at making one view take it's parent's height minus a given constant. Is this possible using auto layout?

Further clarification: I have a view with two containers in it; one which takes 90 pixels at the top, and another one that I want to take the rest of the space, whatever that is. That is, the height of the parent container minus 90. I've been able to manage all other constraints, but not this one.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. You resolved this issue?

Comment: No! I still need it =)

Answer (score 0):

Try this constraints. it will work.

[image: container1 constraints]

[image: container2 constraints]

Select height constraints from pin tap and add costraint

[image: Pin]

Comment: I don't get it. Where's the height constraint?

Comment: @AndréFratelli select the view and add height constraint from pin tap. See the above image and also refer this link https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithConstraints/WorkingwithConstraints.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH8-SW1